# Using transformers class BertForQuestionAnswering for Extractive Question Answering

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm using a BERT model for Extractive QA task with the `transformers` class library `BertForQuestionAnswering`.  Extractive Question Answering is the task of answering a question for a given context text and outputting the start and end indexes of where the answer matches in the context. [My code](https://github.com/loretoparisi/hf-experiments/blob/master/src/bert/run.py) is the following:

```
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
    cache_dir=os.getenv("cache_dir", "../../models"))
question = "What is the capital of Italy?"
text = "The capital of Italy is Rome."
inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, text, return_tensors='pt')
start, end = model(**inputs)
start_max = torch.argmax(F.softmax(start, dim = -1))
end_max = torch.argmax(F.softmax(end, dim = -1)) + 1 ## add one ##because of python list indexing
answer = tokenizer.decode(inputs["input_ids"][0][start_max : end_max])
print(answer)
```

I get this error

```
start_max = torch.argmax(F.softmax(start, dim = -1))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1583, in softmax
    ret = input.softmax(dim)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'softmax'
```

I have also tried this approach, slightly different

```
encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(text=question,text_pair=text, add_special=True)
inputs = encoding['input_ids']  #Token embeddings
sentence_embedding = encoding['token_type_ids']  #Segment embeddings
tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs) #input tokens
start_scores, end_scores = model(input_ids=torch.tensor([inputs]), token_type_ids=torch.tensor([sentence_embedding]))
start_index = torch.argmax(start_scores)
end_index = torch.argmax(end_scores)
answer = ' '.join(tokens[start_index:end_index+1])
```

but the error is likely the same:

```
    start_index = torch.argmax(start_scores)
TypeError: argmax(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str
```

I assume due to the unpack of the output as

```
start, end = model(**inputs)
```

If so, how to correct unpack this model's outputs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Huggingface transformer model returns string instead of logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901831/huggingface-transformer-model-returns-string-instead-of-logits)

Comment: @cronoik hahaha refactoring is the evil 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to version update, the model returns a dictionary and not a tuple of start, end.
You can add the following parameter:
`return_dict=False`