# NLP - Error using detach during evaluation

Tags: python, error-handling, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm very new to nlp topic and it's my first project. I'm trying to follow this code only for RoBERTa: https://github.com/JMSaindon/NlpSquad/blob/master/Bert_fine_tune.ipynb, but have a problem with the evaluation part, getting such an error:
[image]

So, as I understand the problem is in this code part before training:
[image]

And using defined function here:

```
 output = [to_list(output[i]) for output in outputs]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Huggingface transformer model returns string instead of logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901831/huggingface-transformer-model-returns-string-instead-of-logits)